Bic Lighter - Solving subdivision warping issues while cutting holes
I have been a little stuck with this model and I can't seem to figure out how to ground these cuts in the proper way so that my mesh does not warp. In my mind the way it is modelled now should be very smooth, but it has lots of warping around the cuts.
Anyone know of a decent solution? Any on hand example someone could share?


THANK YOU!

UPDATE:
So I think one issue I am having are these loops cuts that are stemming from this cut out on the flame shield. I feel like I should probably be terminating these red lines elsewhere or ground that cut out differently but I have not found a great solution yet, however when I space out those red lines the issue does subside.

Also here is the incomplete .blend.
This is a WIP model and I had not yet figured out how to cut in the tab on the side in combination with the holes on the front. My subd modelling is a bit rusty.


hello do you have a reference image of the real object?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Your problem is that your getting into too much detail with too little topology. You have to think iteratively. Like start with the low-res cylinder shape, get the overall form figured out. Then add one subsurf to get the overall rounded shape. Then once you're happy there apply that and then model with that geo.

You can't expect to go from 8-16 sided cylinder to full model without some compromise. The messed up shading you see is that comporomise.
Your end goal is to have as close to even topology as possible, especially on curved surfaces.
Right here you have huge disparities in the spacing of your geo.

The one on the left has only 2x the cylinder sides and it looks alot better already.

Without modifiers.


Well I have certainly considered when and where to apply modifiers, but I was trying to keep this as simple as possible and often applying subd can lead to a lot of geo on places I don't want it.  I did update the post and include the asset I was working with if you are interested.

This is the nature of 3D modeling. You have to keep it as simple as possible while also adding detail where required to meet the needs of your project. That's just art, in general, really.

I think there are moments where you can't get around a mod commit, but you can absolutely step down the spacing of your geometry in different areas and still have a subd mod work fine. I posted an answer below, essentially giving those ends someplace to go.

It seems to work fine with this topology:

File: 

Hey thanks! So I did try that ( I also uploaded the model to the post if you want to check it out ) and it seems like it still had warping to some affect ...

See my edit, I've linked my file

I got an answer up

Alright, so I finally solved this one.
What ultimately fixed the issue was basically extruding that inner edge, now I planned to do this with the solidify mod, and probably still will knowing that it will fix this issue, though I still would be interested if this shape could be cut out cleanly out of a mesh with no depth 
However most things are 3D and this has 100% cleared up the issue I was having.


